# Python import Tensorflow: segmentation fault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, tensorflow

I am totally new to tensorflow. I just installed a tensorflow0.8.0 for use in Python. I installed it with CPU only by:

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl --user
```

I am working on department computer so I cannot do `sudo`

My python is:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 11 2015, 17:47:16)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
```

When I simply do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

It returns me

```
Segmentation fault
```

However, when I do:

```
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf
```

It works.

So, any idea why this happens? Is it necessary to fix the problem?

[upgrade on May.22] I have read through the issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2034 which fixed the same problem and tried to recompile `scipy` and `numpy` as it suggested in that issue, but the problem still exists. I.e, I have to `import numpy` or `import scipy` before `import tensorflow`. So any idea about this?

Comment: This is an issue [2034](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2034), it should be fixed at head

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov thanks for your comment, I have read through the issue and tried to fix the problem as it suggested in that question, but the problem is still there. I have modified my original question.

Comment: Are u using version at head?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Sorry I didn't get it, what do you mean?

Comment: This problem exists in version 0.8 but it is fixed in version HEAD

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Ah I am using 0.8.0, and you mean install from source? then I didn't...as said in my question

Comment: Yes, get latest tf version from source